unable to populate custom attribute value in woo commerce product using v3 batch update api
https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#batch-update-products
I am trying to use below JSON request to create the product in woo commerce the product is getting created successfully but the custom attribute "ANWENDUNGSBEREICH" is not getting populated can someone please help
API endpoint is: /wp-json/wc/v3/products/batch
[
    'sku' => '101101',
    'name' => 'Test product woo',
    'description' => 'Test description',
    'status' => 'publish',
    'attributes' => [
        [
            'name' => 'ANWENDUNGSBEREICH',
            'position' => 0,
            'visible' => true,
            'variation' => false
        ]
    ]
];

I tried create the above request but the attribute is not getting populated i am expecting someone to share the proper format of request so that attribute gets populated.

Guys I have found the answer for this question, thanks for your help
